# MPI Bcast, other processes are not waiting

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a task:

> Write a program that sends data from the process with the number 0 to
> all other processes along the pipeline. This means that process i must
> accept data from i-1 and send it to process i + 1, and so on until the
> last process is reached. The process with the number 0 reads data
> (integers) from the user until a negative integer is entered.
>
> Complete the task using MPI_Sendrecv exchange.

I  wrote a program, but faced a problem.  When i call MPI_Bcast, other processes are executing and not waiting for the data from process 0.

My idea is to save values from input in list while process 0 is running, after this with MPI_Bcast send to other processes values to their lists. And only then call MP_Sendrecv

As the result, program freezes.

My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int proc_count, proc_this;
int input;
list <int> buf;
list <int> nlist = {};
int siz = 0;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int tag = 1;
    MPI_Status Stat;
    MPI_Request request;
    int prev, next;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_count);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_this);

    prev = proc_this - 1;
    next = proc_this + 1;

    cout << "size before = " << siz << endl;

 
    MPI_Bcast(&siz, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nlist, siz, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    cout << "size = " << siz << endl;


    if (proc_this == 0) {

        cout << "Enter an integer and a non-negative number ";
        cin >> input;
        while (input >= 0) {
            nlist.push_back(input);

            cout << "Enter an integer and a non-negative number ";
            cin >> input;
        }
        cout << "Was entered negative value \n";

        siz = nlist.size();

    }
    else if (proc_this != 0 and proc_this != proc_count - 1) {
        
        
        MPI_Sendrecv(&nlist, siz, MPI_INT, next, tag, &buf, siz, MPI_INT, prev, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
        printf("Proc No-%d send data to proc No-%d\n", prev, next);

        cout << "size siz= " << siz << endl;
        for (auto it = nlist.begin(); it != nlist.end(); it++)
            printf("Proc No-%d my data %d\n", proc_this, *it);

    }
    else 
        printf("Last proc was reached!");


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int proc_count, proc_this;
int input;
vector <int> buf;
vector <int> nlist = {};
int siz;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int tag = 1;
    MPI_Status Stat;
    MPI_Request request;
    int prev, next;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_count);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_this);

    prev = proc_this - 1;
    next = proc_this + 1;

    cout << "size before = " << siz << endl;

    MPI_Bcast(&siz, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&nlist, siz, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&buf, siz, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (proc_this == 0) {

        cout << "Enter an integer and a non-negative number ";
        cin >> input;
        while (input >= 0) {
            nlist.push_back(input);

            cout << "Enter an integer and a non-negative number ";
            cin >> input;
        }
        cout << "Was entered negative value \n";

        siz = nlist.size();
        buf.resize(siz);
    }
    else if (proc_this != 0 and proc_this != proc_count - 1) {
        cout << "buf size = " << buf.size() << endl;
        cout << "size = " << siz << endl;

        MPI_Sendrecv(nlist.data(), siz, MPI_INT, next, tag, buf.data(), siz, MPI_INT, prev, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);

        printf("Proc No-%d send data to proc No-%d\n", proc_this, next);
        cout << "size siz= " << siz << endl;

        for (auto it = nlist.begin(); it != nlist.end(); it++)
            printf("Proc No-%d my data %d\n", proc_this, *it);
    }
    else
        printf("Last proc was reached!");


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

**Another one UPD:**
I fixed the problem with Bcast, but the MPI_Sendrecv stil not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int proc_count, proc_this;
int input;
vector <int> buf = {};
vector <int> nlist = {};
int siz;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int tag = 1;
    MPI_Status Stat;
    MPI_Request request;
    int prev, next;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_count);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_this);

    prev = proc_this - 1;
    next = proc_this + 1;

    cout << "size before = " << siz << endl;


    if (proc_this == 0) {

        cout << "Enter an integer and a non-negative number ";
        cin >> input;
        while (input >= 0) {
            nlist.push_back(input);

            cout << "Enter an integer and a non-negative number ";
            cin >> input;
        }
        cout << "Was entered negative value \n";

        siz = nlist.size();
    }
  
    
    MPI_Bcast(&siz, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    nlist.resize(siz);
    MPI_Bcast(nlist.data(), siz, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    buf.resize(siz);

    if (proc_this != 0 and proc_this != proc_count - 1) {

        cout << "buf size = " << buf.size() << endl;
        cout << "size nlist = " << nlist.size() << endl;

        MPI_Sendrecv(nlist.data(), siz, MPI_INT, next, tag, buf.data(), siz, MPI_INT, prev, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);

        printf("Proc No-%d send data to proc No-%d\n", proc_this, next);
        cout << "size siz= " << siz << endl;

        for (int it: nlist)
            cout << "Proc No- " << proc_this << " my data " << it << endl;
    }
    if (proc_this == proc_count - 1)
        printf("Last proc was reached!");

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: rank `0` does not send anything to rank `1`, hence the deadlock. better use `MPI_PROC_NULL` (as recommended by Victor) to make your code concise **and** correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send a `list` object. MPI can only handle contiguous buffers of simple data types, unless you explicitly teach it how to handle other things.
If you have a `vector<int>` you can get hold of its data with `v.data()`, which is an `int` buffer. With `list` this doesn't work because its data is not contiguous; there is no `.data()` method.

Next, the test `if (proc_this != 0 and proc_this != proc_count - 1)` is unsafe. The second and one-before-last process are trying to communicate with a process that is not reciprocating. That may work but it need not. You should use `MPI_PROC_NULL` for target/send processes that are to be skipped.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your comment. I've changed list to vector in my code
But the problem is still is. MPI_Sendrecv doesn't run after MPI_Bcast.

Comment: I also tried to use nlist.data() in Bcast like this:
```MPI_Bcast(nlist.data(), nlist.size(), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);```
This didn't help.
When i commented line with MPI_sendrecv, the program result was 
```size before = 0
size before = 0
size before = 0
Enter an integer and a non-negative number
buf size = 0
size = 0
Proc No-1 send data to proc No-2
size siz= 0
7
Enter an integer and a non-negative number 3
Enter an integer and a non-negative number -2
Was entered negative value
Last proc was reached! ```

Comment: Did you also address the problem that you need `MPI_PROC_NULL` for the end points?

Comment: I tried it before and it didn't work. I guess there was anything else wrong.

I just tried to do it again with new code and it worked))

Thank you all for your help